# "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined" in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Im getting the error in the title in my Angular 2 script, when retrieving data via my service, but the page component is still showing the info, using {{ bedriften }}, even though i get the error. I dont know what im doing wrong. When i call console.log(this.bedriften) it is undefined, but is displayed on the page. Im unsure how to load information properly before the page is shown to user (i mean so the this.bedriften is populated)

My service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HendingService {
alleHendingar: any;
data: any;
constructor(private http: Http) { }
bed: any;

hentHendingar() {
return this.http.get("http://ekstremedia.no/rapporter/allehendingar.json")
  .map(res => res.json()); 
}
hentBedrift(bed) {
  return this.http.get("http://localhost:81/vossapp/get/bedrift/"+bed)
  .map(res => res.json()); 
  }  
}
```

My page , where i get the error:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HendingService } from '../../hending-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bedriftside',
  templateUrl: './bedriftside.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bedriftside.component.scss'],
  providers: [HendingService]
})

export class BedriftsideComponent implements OnInit {
 id: number;
 private sub: any;
 bedriften: any;
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private hs: HendingService) { }

ngOnInit() {

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = params['id']; 
    });  

   this.hs.hentBedrift(this.id)
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.bedriften = data
  });    
    console.log(this.bedriften);  // undefined
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the console.log outside the subscribe, you should be able to access it once the response is received

```
  this.hs.hentBedrift(this.id)
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.bedriften = data;
       console.log(this.bedriften); 
  });
```

Also in the template you need to check if the value exists using the safe navigation operator

```
<h1> {{bedriften?.title}}</h1>
```

Comment: But, on the page component i do {{bedriften.title}} and I get this error message in console: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined. But on the page it displays the title correct. It works, but obviously im doing somthing wrong.

Comment: you can use safe navigation operator {{bedriften?.title}}

Comment: That works. Is this a common practice to do?

Comment: yes! its a common practice, because you are making asynchronous calls and you have to wait for the response

Comment: Can you write it as an answer so i can accept it? If that is how I should do this? I also just learned that i could do ngIf on the variable thanks to you.

Comment: @TerjeNesthus done

Comment: As a person with 55k+ rep and commonly answering in the angular tag, you should realize that this is a common question. Redirect the users to the existing resources @Sajeetharan

Comment: its not a common question, read the entire comments before commenting

Comment: Google 'cannot read property of undefined angular2 http'. At least 2 other SO questions describe the same problem/solution.

Comment: Sorry, I'll learn from this and thank you for the help @Sajeetharan!